# Почему в toolbare меню прячется?

Tags: android

Прописал по мануалу, а иконки в toolbar групирует и прячет, вот код меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/robobet_calendar_text"
      android:title="дата"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/robobet_calendar"
    android:title="календарь"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_calendar_default"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

а вот скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А им хватает места? Что происходит с ними при изменении ориентации экрана?

Comment: да, когда оставляю один календарь также он один в группе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в xml `namespace` app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/robobet_calendar_text"
        android:title="дата"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/robobet_calendar"
        android:title="календарь"
        android:icon="@drawable/white_calendar_default"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Спасибо, пора идти спать)))). Пропустил xmlns:app....